# Automatically starting skype with pulse latency set to 60ms

Tags: skype, audio, pulseaudio

I use OpenSuse 13.1. There is a bug in pavucontrol with skype, that causes a terrible noise when starting skype.

It is solved by killing skype and starting it with

```
>> PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype
```

This is great.

Now I don't want to kill/restart skype manually on each boot.

I read that I could add this line to skype.desktop:

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

I did this, but still same problem.

Also, I seem to have two skype.desktop files (one in /home/dorien/bin/skype-4.2.0.11/ and one in the 4.2.0.13). I have changed the line in both, but no effect.

Does Opensuse (13.1) not read this when starting? Or is there another way to control the startup option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new skype version 3.x supports pulseaudio, so updating to this version makes this hack unnecessary.